# When running Connect-ExchangeOnline I am getting "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0" error

Tags: .net, powershell, exchange-server, windows-server

I just successfully installed ExchangeOnlineManagement PowerShell module on a server that has .Net 4.0 installed and two versions of PowerShell (5.1 and 7). I am able to import the module but when I try to connect "Connect-ExchangeOnline" I get an error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system
cannot find the file specified.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\3.1.0\netFramework\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:729 char:21

- ```
                  throw $_.Exception.InnerException;
  ```
- ```
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], FileNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of
    its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: First check with file explorer to see of file exists.  You may need Admin to run so start PS by clicking on PS shortcut and select Run Admin

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking into the version of .NET Framework you are running. I could not run ExchangeOnlineManagement PowerShell module 3.1.0 on .NET Framework 4.6.2, but I could on .NET Framework 4.8. (ref. https://funwithiagengineering.blogspot.com/2023/06/issue-migrating-to-exchangeonlinemanage.html)